# Unable to match the required phone number format

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to match a phone number format using preg_match in PHP but I am unable to achieve success.

Phone number format that I am trying to match is:

+92XXXXXXXXXX

First three characters should be +92 and the rest of the remaining should have a count of 10 and should be numbers from 0 to 9. Here it is what I am trying but unable to match:

```
preg_match('/^[+92]{3}[0-9]{10}$/',$phone_number) )
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using:

```
^(\+92\d{10})$
```

The problem in `^[+92]{3}[0-9]{10}$` is in `[+92]`. What you are doing is saying match either of `+,9,2` three times. Therefore that include cases like `+++`, `999`, `299`, `29+` and many more.

To correct you pattern, change `[+92]{3}` to `\+92`. Therefore it would be:

```
^\+92[0-9]{10}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern works, bot not for literal `+92XXXXXXXXXX` - with digits in place of `X` it works. However if it always begins with +92, change the pattern to:

```
^\+92[0-9]{10}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/nG6wI1/1